# Read-only pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am just curious to know if there is a way to forbid the modification of a pointer passed to a function if a second pointer is declared within that function.

Say we've got the next function:

```
void foo(double* ptr1){
     double* ptr2;
     ptr2 = ptr1;
     ptr2[0] = 0.0; 
}
```

Whenever this function is called I have found no way of forbidding (with a compiler error or any other way) the modification of `ptr1`.

Comment: not really, I read that one but I could not find an answer

Comment: What exactly looking for? Error on `ptr1 = somenewadd;` or `*ptr1 = somenewvalue` both are answered.

Comment: You can always assign a `const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer without compiler throwing an error. So the answer is **no**. It will, however, throw a warning and attempting to change the value pointed to by it will invoke undefined behaviour. Write a small program and try it out yourself. Turn on the flag `-Wall`. See what warnings you get.